# WD Advanced Format confusion

Tags: debian, partition, grub2

One of my *Hitachi DeskStar 7K160* hard disks died today and the other one is not safe (has bad sectors) so I've ordered a new 1 TB [WD Blue WD10EZEX](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=770). Apparently nowadays new hard disks come with this *Advanced Format* technology. I don't know much about hard disk partitioning, cylinders, blocks, aligning &c. but as I read, wrong type of configuration can cause problems such as slower R/W speeds, loss of capacity &c.

This is how I would like to partition the new drive:

**win7(NTFS) | storage1 (NTFS) | swap | debian jessie (EXT4) | storage2 (EXT4)** *

Should I just use Debian's partition manager (on *netinstall*, I guess it's `gparted` based?) -as I always do- then install win7 **(64-bit)** and then install Debian and I should not encounter any problems? If not, should I worry about:

- What partition manager should I employ?
- [This wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Format) suggest that I use GPT instead of MBR. But I have an [old motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2539#ov) with BIOS, no UEFI. Can I use GPT at all?
- Is having windows on the same hard disk with Debian gonna screw things up?
- ***Just what is the correct procedure to partition this new hard disk?!***

*: The order of the partitions can be different if this order is gonna cause problems.

Comment: I don't know about the GPT support of Windows, but GPT does work on BIOS systems perfectly well, so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you don't need to worry about it as partitioning tools were patched years ago to handle this.  Also "Advanced Format" has nothing to do with GPT; you only need to use that for disks > 2 TiB or if you are using UEFI.  Windows does not support GPT without UEFI.

Comment: So should I go with MBR since if I make GPT then GRUB won't be able to boot Windows (since I have no UEFI)?

Comment: @sterz, yep....